# Ruby: how to print function calling trace?

Tags: ruby

When I use C++, there is convenient macro that I can add at the beginning of each function to print the information of the function being called, also with proper indentation (see example below). I wonder if there is similar tool in Ruby. Thanks a lot.

```
int A (int a, int b)
{
  TRACE("%d", a);
  B(b);
  ...
}

int B (int b)
{
  TRACE("%d", b);
  ...
}
```

Runtime output,

```
==> A(a)
====> B(b)
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's called [`caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller).

```
def foo
  p caller
  # ...
end
```

The method returns the current execution stack — an array containing strings in the form file:line or file:line: in `method'.

For better formatting, you can use `pp` instead of `p` to print out the stack.

```
require 'pp'
def foo
  pp caller
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is the `p` function:

This would print information regarding the object `a`

```
p a
```

Another nice tool is the `inspect` method.

```
a.inspect
```

Comment: `p` also returns the argument object, so you could like you would for `a.inspect`, such as if you were logging it.  But also have the output to STDOUT.